# dropbox chooser 403 error for webapp on iPad/iPhone

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am new to dropbox.I have tried to integrate dropbox chooser and it worked well with the code given on the official site for developers at https://www.dropbox.com/developers on the desktop browsers.But when I tried to do it with iPhode or iPad it gives me 403 error irrespective to i have logged in or not.

So,Please guide me further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it and the error was i put localhost.

Answer (score 2):

you must test your ip addresses.